# Is it correct to write or say "Am I seeing the dawn in my twilight?"

Tags: description, self-publishing

Is it correct to write "Am I seeing the dawn in my twilight?"

Comment: It could be a very poetic way of saying you are perceiving the morning in the glow of pre-dawn twilight (looking forward to the dawn). How are you intending the sentence to mean? Or a VERY poetic way of saying you foresee renewal in the face of decline (like a new phase of life in retirement).

Comment: If your question is less about literary usage than if this is proper English, this might not be the right site for you. It might be English SE https://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you so much DWKraus for your prompt reply. You aptly expounded on what the question may want to evoke such as to "foresee renewal in the face of decline". 

More power and God bless you!

Comment: It's a mixed metaphor. It is not 'correct', but the meaning is easy to grasp and it might reveal something about the person saying it (ie: character, humor, irony, chronic-positivity) https://www.studiobinder.com/blog/what-is-a-mixed-metaphor-definition/

Comment: If it is said by someone used to living where there is very little to no actual night darkness  for part of the year (Ex: the far north on earth) then it makes sense to me even as a practicality of expression too maybe? (It could literally refer to it brightening again despite only ever achieving twilight levels of darkness - and as such can be associated with feelings and emotions that themselves that moment might bring.)